# How to set a target="_blank" in a DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

Got a page that displays some buttons (background images, etc) and they are all clickable. What I want this specific button to do is open the target page in another browser tab using *target="_blank"*. The way it is setup as the href in a *div* I cannot do this. Any ideas on a work around for this?

```
<div class="dashboard_navbutton" href="Home/RequestRedirect" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Form_button.png")');">
    <p>Insert witty text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of HTML? Yes, that matters.

Comment: HTML4 (or XHTML 1.0 transitional to be exact)

Comment: `href` attributes on a `div` don't validate under HTML4 or XHTML1. I seem to remember it was going to be allowed in XHTML2, but XHTML2 never happened. So HTML5 is the only DOCTYPE you can use here. Unless you switch the order of the tags around (put the `a` element inside the `p`).

Answer (score 8):

Just make that `div` an `a` and add `display:block;` to the `style`.

EDIT: Ensure that your chosen `DOCTYPE` supports the use of `p` inside an `a` element. More generally, it should use the computed style for `display` rather than the tag name to determine if an element is `inline` or `block` in terms of having one in the other. I believe the HTML5 one is fine: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: agreed. having a `div` with an `href` is a hideous hack

Comment: Yea, `href` attribute should not be on a `div`.  If you are trying to open a new window via a button, then a `button` tag is your best bet with some javascript using `window.open`.

Comment: Well, not all HTML dialects like a `<p>` in an `<a>`, so you should suggest putting the `<a>` in the `<p>` or making sure the DOCTYPE is set right.

Comment: That's true. I believe the HTML5 Doctype allows it? (It certainly seems to allow tables and `hr`s and a bunch of other stuff in them that probably shouldn't be :p)

Comment: I'll try the a and display:block style. BTW I didn't design the original page. Just trying to modify the existing link that's there. Had no idea you could put a href in a div tag.

Comment: What browsers/html version even obeys `href` on `div`?

Comment: I have no idea. You can of course put an `href` attribute on anything, but I think it only has meaning on an `<a>`...

Comment: Er right, that's what I meant by obey (meaningless attributes aside :p).  Either way, I'm not really sure how the other links Valien had ever worked based on the snippet presented.

Answer (score 1):

trap the onclick event for the div, call a javascript function, have the function openthe window.

html snippet
onclick="opennewwin()"

```
function opennewwin(){
    var awindow = window.open(loc, "blank", "height=500px,width=500px");

}
```

Comment: This kind of thing would work for sure, but semantically it makes more sense to use `<button>` instead of `<div>` in your markup; actually the best bet would be an unordered list `<ul>` with the new HTML5 `<nav>` wrapped around using `<a>` in each of your `<li>` items.  You can use javascript and/or CSS pseudo classes for button-like presentation.

Comment: Unless you are posting this on an intranet, I wouldn't use HTML5 yet.  too many old browsers out there that won't handle it.  But you can use your solution in an older standard and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to dynamically add divs that would also function as links.
This was my solution using CSS.

First the container needs relative positioning.

```
.container {position: relative;}
```

Next, the link needs to fill the container.

```
.container a {position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

Like I said, I dynamically assembled the div, but the html would look something like this:

```
<div class='container'>[some other content]<a href="link"></a></div>
```

The container must be position relative, otherwise the position absolute link fills its first position relative ancestor (probably the whole viewport).
Of course, you can add styling to the div or the link. Note, I was using a position: sticky nav-bar, and I had to set it's z-index high in order to avoid collisions with the div buttons.

Pros: whatever styling and targeting you set for your links will apply.  Good 'style': doesn't put a block element inside an inline (should avoid browser issues, though I haven't thoroughly tested it).  Does not require any other languages or frameworks.

Cons: Not as simple as Niet's answer, but shouldn't be Doctype dependent.